# to obtain a process having maximum CPU usage

Tags: process, cpu-usage

I am trying to write a C code to extract a process which has the maximum CPU utilization(CPU %). I have checked out the top command's implementation but could not find any relevant information about it. What exactly do I have to use in order to get information about the process having maximum CPU% through a C program? A command would also work.

Comment: there's no magical "get top", you get a list of cpu usage of all programs, sort it, then pick off the first/last value, as appropriate.

Comment: Use [the source](https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/master/top.c#L932), Luke.

Comment: The command worked. But, can you give me some idea about how I can write a C code to do the same job?